# How to create function for custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating one simple custom jQuery plugin using [jquery.boilerplate.js](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js). Now I want to create one function that will call like,

```
var div1 = $("#div1").changeBackgroundColor({
  color: $('#colorCode').val().trim()
});
div1.getColor();
```

How to defined that `getColor()` method in jquery plugin.

**Custom Plugin:**

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
var pluginName = "changeBackgroundColor", defaults = {
    color : "black"
};

function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

$.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init : function() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
});

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this,
                    options));
            }
        console.log(options);
        if(options===undefined){
            $(this).css("background-color", defaults.color);
        } else{ 
            $(this).css("background-color", options.color);
        }
    });
    return this;
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Thank You....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda missed the whole point of plugins and OOP.

1. `$.fn[pluginName]` - should play infrastructure role and delegate actual work to the `Plugin` instance.
2. `Plugin` instance should perform actual work with element.
3. If you want to call methods on `Plugin` instances you can make `$.fn[pluginName]` to handle special cases when `options` is a string. `$(selector).changeBackgroundColor('methodToBeCalled' /*rest arguments*/)`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/8zvxh2ao/).

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
var pluginName = "changeBackgroundColor", 
    defaults = {
        color : "black"
    },
    //methods to be called via $().changeBackgroundColor(name)
    publicMethods = { 
        getColor: function() {
            return this.settings.color;        
        },
        setColor: function(color) {
            this.settings.color = color;
            this.element.css('background-color', color);            
        }
    },
    privateMethods = { //internal methods
        init : function() {
            console.log('init');
            this.setColor(this.getColor());            
        }
};

function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = $(element);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    this.init();
}

//copy private and public methods
$.extend(Plugin.prototype, privateMethods, publicMethods); 

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    var out = [],
        args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    this.each(function() {
        var plugin = $.data(this, pluginName), 
            method;

        if (!plugin) { //create new plugin  
            plugin = new Plugin(this, options)                  
            return $.data(this, pluginName, plugin);            
        }
        //handle method calls
        if(typeof options === 'string' && publicMethods[options]) { 
            out.push(plugin[options].apply(plugin, args));
        }        
    });
    return out.length ? (out.length === 1 ? out[0] : out) : this;
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Usage

```
$('#a').changeBackgroundColor();
$('#b').changeBackgroundColor({color: 'navy'});
$('#c').changeBackgroundColor({color: 'green'});
console.log($('#b').changeBackgroundColor('getColor'));
console.log($('#b, #c').changeBackgroundColor('getColor'));

$('#a').changeBackgroundColor('setColor', 'red');
console.log($('#a').changeBackgroundColor('getColor'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your method like this

```
$.fn.getColor = function() { 
     alert('getColor called'); 
}
```

**[Basic Custom Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)**

Comment: You can define it in your custome plugin or if you are going to use it in your html page only then you can define it in that page.

Comment: See [basic custom plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) for your reference.

Comment: @bhushan...getting error on `div1.getColor()` -> `undefined is not a function`. Thanks

Comment: check if `div1` is undefined or null

Comment: @bhushan...anything wrong in this code? `var div1 = $("#div1").changeBackgroundColor({
  color: $('#colorCode').val().trim()
});
div1.getColor();`

Comment: use `alert(div1);` before `div1.getColor();` and check if div1 is null or undefined. `div1` should be `[object]` otherwise it will give error on calling `div1.getColor();`

Answer (score 0):

Create your Plugin like this:

```js
$.fn.highlight = function(){
  this.css("background","yellow").css("color","black");
  return this;
}

$(".highlight").highlight().fadeIn();
```

In the above example i had created a simple jQuery plugin which will highlight a element.I think you should check this http://mycodingtricks.com/jquery/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-plugin/